# In Redux - is there any difference between using store.dispatch() and dispatch()?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there any difference between store.dispatch() and dispatch() when creating an action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `store.dispatch` you need to have a reference to the store, so your components become coupled with it (you need to import the exact store). The `dispatch` is provided with the store's reference coming from a context, so you don't have to worry if the correct value will be passed.

Comment: Thanks! @MateuszKocz